# How do I add columns together after Google Script runs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to run the following google script then additionally input in column E (on the same row), 53- Column D (esentially =sum(53-D).

So the desired result in Google Sheets would be the following.  The last number, 33 is what I'm trying to generate (53-20).  So the 6th column (F) is the sum of 53-Column E.

1   2/5/2021 11:48:16   distance    20  33

```
// This method will be called first or hits first  
function doGet(e){
  Logger.log("--- doGet ---");
 
 var tag = "",
     value = "";
 
  try {
 
    // this helps during debuggin
    if (e == null){e={}; e.parameters = {tag:"test",value:"100"};}
 
    tag = e.parameters.tag;
    value = e.parameters.value;
 
    // save the data to spreadsheet
    save_data(tag, value);
 
 
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Wrote:\n  tag: " + tag + "\n  value: " + value);
 
  } catch(error) { 
    Logger.log(error);    
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("oops...." + error.message 
                                            + "\n" + new Date() 
                                            + "\ntag: " + tag +
                                            + "\nvalue: " + value);
   }
}
// Method to save given data to a sheet
function save_data(tag, value){
  Logger.log("--- save_data ---"); 
 
 
  try {
    var dateTime = new Date();
 
    // Paste the URL of the Google Sheets starting from https thru /edit
    // For e.g.: https://docs.google.com/..../edit 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/rtFs-TCHNfbiu3UJy7YOHI/edit");
    var summarySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Summary");
    var dataLoggerSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DataLogger");
 
 
    // Get last edited row from DataLogger sheet
    var row = dataLoggerSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
 
 
    // Start Populating the data
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("A" + row).setValue(row -1); // ID
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B" + row).setValue(dateTime); // dateTime
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C" + row).setValue(tag); // tag
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("D" + row).setValue(value); // value
 
 
    // Update summary sheet
    summarySheet.getRange("B1").setValue(dateTime); // Last modified date
    // summarySheet.getRange("B2").setValue(row - 1); // Count 
 
  }
 
  catch(error) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
 
  Logger.log("--- save_data end---"); 
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add:

```
    // Start Populating the data
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("A" + row).setValue(row -1); // ID
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B" + row).setValue(dateTime); // dateTime
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C" + row).setValue(tag); // tag
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("D" + row).setValue(value); // value
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("E" + row).setValue(53-value); // 53 - value
```

Comment: Wow.  This was WAY more efficient than the route I was trying to do.  Thanks!